# Flexmix package in R - extracting from Flexmix output object into dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, r-s4

I have output from a 2-component mixture model run using the Flexmix package in R.  I am trying to extract the list of model coefficients, which is stored in what seems to be a list(mix2@components$Comp.1) inside an object of "Formal class FLXcomponent". I would like to store the estimates from each component ins separate dataframes.

```
### Simulated data for regression mixture model using Flexmix
### Class 1
x<-seq(from=1,to=2, by=0.01)
y<-seq(from=0,to=1, by=0.01)
z<-x+y+y^2
class_label <- c(rep(c(1), length(z)))
dat1<-data.frame(x,y,z,class_label)
### Class2
x<-seq(from=2,to=3, by=0.01)
y<-seq(from=10,to=11, by=0.01)
z<-x^2+y+y^2
class_label <- c(rep(c(2), length(z)))
dat2<-data.frame(x,y,z,class_label)
simdat<-rbind(dat1,dat2)

### Run the model
mix2 <- flexmix(z ~ x+y+x^2+y^2, data=simdat, k=2)
out2<-summary(mix2)
out2
### Extract model coefficients for Component 1
mix2@components$Comp.1
str(mix2@components$Comp.1)
mix2@components[[1]][["Comp.1"]][,1]
mix2@components$Comp.1[,1]
```

I tried using the getSlots() function in R on mix2, but this gives an error:

```
getSlots(mix2@components$Comp.1)
Error in .getClassesFromCache(Class) : 
  class should be either a character-string name or a class definition
```

How can I extract the coefficients in the model components and save them in a dataframe?
For instance, neither of the approaches below works:

```
outdat<-as.data.frame(mix2@components[[1]][["Comp.1"]][,1])
outdat<-as.data.frame(mix2@components$Comp.1)
```

Comment: `getSlots` is meant to be given a *class name*, not an object. Try `getSlots(class(mix2))` instead, and find a slot that is a data frame or similar class. Alternatively, is there a method for `coef` (or `coefficients`) for this class?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, although I am open to other (better) approaches.

mix2 <- flexmix(z ~ I(x^2)+I(y^2), data=simdat, k=2)

p1<-parameters(mix2, component=1)[[1]]
p2<-parameters(mix2, component=1)[[2]]
and so on.